# How to store the categories to an array variable in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I store the categories names and IDs into an array in Wordpress?

Comment: There is a wordpress stackexhange site also http://wordpress.stackexhange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_categories()` will give you an array to work with, and you can use PHP array functions to slice it up as you need to.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
 $cat = array();
 $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
   foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) {
     $cat[]['id'] = $cat_id;
     $cat[]['name'] = get_cat_name($cat_id);
   }
```